# Visual Studio 2012 install and .NET SDK

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to get MSBuild working via the Microsoft.Build library (ie. not via the command line exe). This is giving me the following error:

> Could not locate the .NET Framework SDK.  The task is looking for the
>   path to the .NET Framework SDK at the location specified in the
>   SDKInstallRootv2.0 value of the registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework.  You may be able
>   to solve the problem by doing one of the following:  1.) Install the
>   .NET Framework SDK.  2.) Manually set the above registry key to the
>   correct location. Normal : No resources are out of date with respect
>   to their source files. Skipping resource generation.

The app I'm writing will be used internally by a few people - all of whom will have VS2012 installed, but probably not explictly installed the SDK. Is the .NET Framework SDK not included in the VS2012 install? I've had a look through the directories, but not really sure what files the msbuild libraries needs, so don't really know what I'm looking for. The only directory I can see which looks similar is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\SDK
```

But this just contains an empty `v3.5\bin` folder.

It sounds like everyone using this app will need to explicitly install the SDK aswell as Visual Studio. Is this correct, or are the required files installed as part of the VS install?

Comment: You not being able to find this required registry key just confirms what msbuild already told you.  Sounds to me you are trying to build on machine that doesn't have either VS or the Windows SDK installed.  That cannot work.

Comment: @HansPassant I think you've misunderstood my question. All machines have VS2012. I'm still getting the above error. I'm wondering whether I need to install the .NET SDK *aswell*, or can I just create a `SDKInstallRootv2.0` registry entry and point it at an existing VS2012 folder?

Comment: No, that's included with the VS setup.  Not seeing the registry key is something to worry about, just hacking the registry by hand isn't terribly likely to solve *every* problem you could run in when the install didn't do what it was supposed to do.  If this goes wrong on more than one machine then I have no reasonable guess at what could be the cause.

Comment: Ah, I've just noticed that it's gone into the `Wow6432Node` node. I've just changed my app to x86, and this has fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the help - your comment stating that the VS install should actually create this registry entry made me search further for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was because Visual Studio put the registry key in the following location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework
```

Note the `Wow6432Node`. Changing my app from `Any CPU` to `x86` resolved the issue.